# Embedding property of subgroups: Strongly Pronormal

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, maximal-subgroup

**Definition :** A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is said to **strongly pronormal** in $G$, if for each $g\in G$ and for any subgroup $K \leq H$, there exists $x\in \langle H, K^g \rangle$ such that $K^{gx} \leq H$.

It is clear that every normal subgroup is strongly pronormal in $G$.

> Let $G$ be a finite group. Then any maximal subgroup of $G$ is strongly pronormal in $G$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $M$ be a non-normal maximal subgroup of $G$. Then we must have that $M=N_G(M)$. Let $g \in G \setminus M$ and $K \leq M$. Since $M \leq \langle M, K^g \rangle \leq G$, we have that $M = \langle M, K^g \rangle$ or $G = \langle M, K^g \rangle$. In the first case, we get that $K^g =M$, and so $M$ is strongly pronormal in $G$.

For the case $G = \langle M, K^g \rangle$, I can't seem to draw a conclusion from this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I assume you meant that "$K$ and $K^g$ are conjugate in $\langle H,K^g\rangle$" right?

Comment: @Nex, the definition above was correct, I have rephrased it a bit so that it's easier to work with.

Comment: Using your new definition just take $x=g^{-1}$.

Comment: @Nex, Thank you! I just realised this now, once I rephrased the definition. You are welcome to post it up as an answer to the question.